How do I show icons at the top of my tab panels
I have a right side panel in my window.  Inside that right side panel are 4 tab panels.  The icons for my tab controls (top tab not body) does not show.
struct RightPanelView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
            VStack{
                someView1( )
                someView2( )
            }
            .tabItem{ MyImage( "pencil" )}      // TODO These icons do not show up
            .background(Color.purple.opacity(0.2))

            VStack { someView3( dm )}
                .tabItem{ MyImage( "clock" )}
                .padding( 0 )

            VStack { someView4( dm )}
                .tabItem{ MyImage( "circle" )}
                .padding( 0 )
        }
    }
}

I know the System Names are correct since I have a row of buttons just above with the same icons.  I was using Image() before and it has the same issue.
Here is what it looks like:

Edit-1
This is an example of FileMaker


@workingdogsupportUkraine Hey!! I'm not trying to 'select the tab'  This request is trying to display the icons in the tab.  To be clear not in the body of the tab but in small piece that shows at the top of the body.  This item used to to bring a specific tab panel forward..  I'll try to provide a screen shot.

I did not understand the How do I bring that particular tab panel forward,
will remove my comment.

I'll reword the question.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Can you take another look at this?

I think this is yet another SwiftUI bug, that does not display the Images/icons in the tabItems. Only text when using a Label is displayed.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Can you suggest another way to do this?  I'd rather have icons if possible.  Maybe get rid of the tabs and use buttons that display panels that don't have tabs.  Like FileMaker which of course is not a Swift App.

Instead of using a TabView, you could create your own equivalent system,
such as in this example code, adjust the looks as required.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(sidebar: {
            Text("sidebar")
        },
        detail: {
            RightPanelView()
        })
    }
}

enum TabSelection: String {
    case pencil, clock, circle
}

struct RightPanelView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = TabSelection.pencil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button { selectedTab = .pencil } label: { Image(systemName: "pencil") }
                    .border(selectedTab == .pencil ? .blue : .clear)
                Button { selectedTab = .clock } label: { Image(systemName: "clock") }
                    .border(selectedTab == .clock ? .blue : .clear)
                Button { selectedTab = .circle } label: { Image(systemName: "circle") }
                    .border(selectedTab == .circle ? .blue : .clear)
            }.padding(.top, 10)
            Spacer()
            switch selectedTab {
                case .pencil: Text("someView0")
                case .clock: Text("someView1")
                case .circle: Text("someView2")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

Or this:
enum TabSelection: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case pencil, clock, circle
    var id: Int {
        switch self {
            case .pencil: return 1
            case .clock: return 2
            case .circle: return 3
        }
    }
}

struct RightPanelView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = TabSelection.pencil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(TabSelection.allCases) { tab in
                    Button { selectedTab = tab } label: { Image(systemName: tab.rawValue) }
                        .overlay(selectedTab == tab ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .foregroundStyle(.blue).opacity(0.3) : nil)
                }
            }.padding(.top, 10)
            Spacer()
            switch selectedTab {
                case .pencil: Text("someView0")
                case .clock: Text("someView1")
                case .circle: Text("someView2")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


kk, just saw this TY.  I'll study it next time I sit down to program.  I have split the views into several pieces so I'll have to figure out how to display multiple views in a single panel but I'll study this.

OK, the second suggestion is definitely the BEST solution.  I got it up and running in about 5m.  I pulled the answer into a re-usable PanelTabStyle: ButtonStyle struct.  Your enum will need to extend String as well if you want to use SF Symbols with periods in them (case someTab = "some.Icon".  I  have to use Customized icon sizes, colors and I'm finalizing appearance now.

if my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green. Note my enum extends String.
